# Google reCAPTCHA does not render for 2nd form after submission of 1st form

Tags: recaptcha

I am using 2 forms in one of my web page.

Initially reCAPTCHA comes for both forms and works fine.

But the problem is, if I first submit data for 1st form, then reCAPTCHA does not come for 2nd form. It works fine for vice versa.

Here is the code in between head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var recaptcha1;
var recaptcha2;
var onloadCallBack = function() {

//Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
'sitekey' : MyDataSiteKey,
'theme' : 'light'
});

//Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
'sitekey' : MyDataSiteKey,
'theme' : 'light'
});               
};
</script>
```

I have put following before end of body tag.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=bn&onload=onloadCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

If I change the sequence (i.e. recaptcha2 first and then recaptcha1), then same happens with 1st form and reCAPTCHA works fine for 2nd form.

Appreciate help from anyone.

Comment: How about you add your html code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CaptchaCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {'sitekey' : '6Lc_your_site_key'});
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {'sitekey' : '6Lc_your_site_key'});
    };
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Note: this only works for v2.0. I think there is no possible method if you are using the original version 1.0

Comment: Sorry! It does not change the result. Anyway, thank you for your prompt response.